# Vue: Unhandled promise rejection Error: Request failed with status code 404？

Tags: vue.js

My API url is http://localhost:5000/api/user/list, data shows as:

```
[{"Id":1,"name":"Michael","pwd":"123456","age":0,"birth":"2018-01-05","addr":"''"},{"Id":2,"name":"Jack","pwd":"123512616","age":0,"birth":"2018-01-05","addr":"''"}]
```

User.vue

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            filters: {
                name: ''
            },
            loading: false,
            users: [
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getUser: function () {
            axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/user/list', function (data) {
                this.$set('users', data);
            })
}
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getUser();
    }
});
```

The error is :
Unhandled promise rejection Error: Request failed with status code 404(…)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should register a handler for your axios request.

Currently you are using settings argument as a handler.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/user/list').then(function (response) {
  // this is your handler.
})
```

Btw, make sure you are not requesting via CORS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a spelling mistake in URL string. It is fixed after that correction.