# Vue: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "Error: Request failed with status code 404"

Tags: express, vue.js, axios

I was following along [this tutorial on youtube](https://youtu.be/Fa4cRMaTDUI?t=3262) when I got the following error (I already left a comment there, hoping somebody got the same issue or knows how to solve it). Basically, in this part of the tutorial Cody shows how to build a register form with express and vue. The error occurs when I click the register button.

**Error message**

```
POST http://localhost:8080/register 404 (Not Found)
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "Error: Request failed with status code 404"
found in

---> <Register> at src/components/Register.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
vue.esm.js?efeb:1897 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
    at settle (settle.js?db52:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:59)
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "Error: Request failed with status code 404"
```

**Directory structure** (only relevant parts)

```
├── client
│   └── src
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── HelloWorld.vue
│   │   └── Register.vue
│   ├── router
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── services
│       ├── Api.js
│       └── AuthenticationService.js
└── server
    └── src
    └── app.js
```

**client/src/components/Register.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <input
      type="email"
      name="email"
      v-model="email"
      placeholder="email">
    <input
      type="password"
      name="password"
      v-model="password"
      placeholder="Password">
    <button
      @click="register">Register
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async register () {
      await AuthenticationService.register({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**client/src/services/AuthenticationService.js**

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
  register (credentials) {
    return Api()
      .post('register')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
      })
  }
}
```

**client/src/services/Api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseUrl: `http://localhost:8081/`
  })
}
```

**client/src/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Register from '@/components/Register'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: Register
    }
  ]
})
```

**server/src/app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();
app.use(morgan("combine"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    message: `Hello Your user was registered. Have fun!`
  })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081);
```

Now, I've already looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179456/vue-unhandled-promise-rejection-error-request-failed-with-status-code-404) and [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960). But I can't figure out the problem. I would be grateful for any hints. BTW I hope the style of this question is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
baseUrl: `http://localhost:8081/`
```

Note that the error message refers to `http://localhost:8080/register`, using port `8080` rather than `8081`, implying that `baseUrl` isn't working.

The axios documentation, https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config, suggests that this setting is called `baseURL`, not `baseUrl`.

Comment: omg.. yes, baseURL is correct. I changed it, and then it worked. Thanks a lot!